# Overriding ArrayList<> for Specific Object for libGDX Game

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, libgdx

Please go easy on me if this is a simple question (it's my first time asking one), I am still a beginner with libGDX and working on my first game.

**Background:**
I need to keep a list of "Gem" objects for a game I am working on in a list. Currently I am using an ArrayList, however I am using multiple helper methods. Unfortunately, because I am only using a generic ArrayList all of these helper methods have to be in my main game class.

**My Question:**
In an effort to keep my code as clean as possible, is there a way to override the entire ArrayList class just for my "Gem" object, so that I can add all of my helper methods, and still be able to use the Java defined ArrayList<> for other objects? Or do I have to create a type of pseudo ArrayList class that implements all the methods associated with an ArrayList? This just seems very tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. Do you want to extend a ArrayList so that you can only put in instances of the class `Gem`? If so you can easily do it like this:

```
public class GemList extends ArrayList<Gem> {
 //All your helper methods
}
```

And use it like this:

```
GemList gemList = new GemList();
gemList.add(new Gem());
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite vague.  I'm not sure what you intend with your "Helper methods".  You can just extend ArrayList and add your methods to that class signature.  Overrides are up to your discretion based on the limited information you've given.

```
public class MyList extends ArrayList<T> { 
    public MyList() { super(); }
}
```

One question, though.  Your helper methods... are these methods stuff like traversal, selection, removal, etc.?  If so, I suggest you choose a different data structure.  You can use a tree structure for easier navigation based on states/variables/position, HashMaps for o(1) based on a key, linked lists to be able to get neighbor nodes, etc.

Comment: Also, there are a ton of helper methods in managing data sets in the Collections framework.  Try Collections.sort, Collections.swap, etc.